# PHP/SQL - Query not showing all data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's the code:

```
            <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['results']) && $_POST['results'] != -1) {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;charset=utf8', '', '');

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Courses</th>
            </tr>";

            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM course WHERE `subject_id`=?");
            $stmt->execute(array($_POST['results']));

            if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                     while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td>", $row['title'], "</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";

                     }

            } else {
                    echo "No results found";
                } echo "</table>"; 
            }

            ?>
```

This is just returning one result into the table, when there are more results to show.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

remove the if, because it's change the pointer of array(fetch)

```
if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // get the first record, remove this if
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {// get the second record and reset $row
```

you can change to:

```
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

if($total_rows > 0){

   foreach($row as $item){
      echo '<td>'. $item['title'] .'</td>';
   }
}else{
  echo 'no results';
}
```

Comment: But I want the if statement for when there is no results

Comment: @tom, so get the array with fetchAll() and count() the numbers of line.

```$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = count($rows);
if($count > 0) {
//some
}else{
   echo 'empty results';
}```

Comment: i change the answer, look again.

Comment: That's worked apart from the table is messing up. The other results are going off to the right (not in the table) instead of under formatted in the table.

Comment: @Tom, the line echo "<td>", $row['title'], "</td>";.  I don't work with PHP much but can you have commas there?

Comment: I think it's because the echo "</table>"; was removed. Unsure where it should go.